# Trigger linux command using external web service

Tags: linux, twitter

I am looking at different options of triggering linux command on NATed box that has internet access.
I know that I could use combination of IMAP box in DMZ, send email to that box and then use como of fetchmail and procmail to trigger script.Can I do something similiar with twitter?e.g. send twitter message from mobile and have some check running on linux box that triggers script.Security is a separate issue, I am just interested in functionality right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I used ttytter in script mode with some perl around it.Seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to periodically run a script which grabs your (or a specific) twitter feed
and parses for commands.  The script could then run particular commands based on the contents of the feed.

There are PERL and python modules you could use to parse the twitter feed or various
command line twitter clients which should also work.

The [PERL Net::Twitter module](http://search.cpan.org/~mmims/Net-Twitter-3.17001/lib/Net/Twitter.pod) could be used to do this.  There are examples of
how to use it in the link.  There are plenty of examples around the web.
A command line program like [TTYtter](http://www.floodgap.com/software/ttytter/) could also be configured and then called from your
script to get the output of your Twitter feed.

hth

Comment: Thank you.Maybe my question was vague.I am aware of perl being a universal glue.I was looking for more specific answers  like module A or module B.

Answer (score 0):

This script is helpful too https://github.com/jalada/twitter-to-omnifocus